# Array element as an index to a different array

Tags: c, arrays, string, permutation

I came across some examples where an array is indexed based on values from a different array.
Example:

```
 char s[] = "aloha";
int l= strlen(s);
int array_count[256];
memset(array_count,0,256*sizeof(int));

for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
 array_count[s[i]]++;// What exactly happens in this statement ??
}
```

I understood it as it checking and setting the alphabets in s[] as 1's in the array array_count,which is the alphabet set. Is that right ?

Comment: It is calculating the histogram of the input string. `array_count` is the histogram of `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is keeping a histogram of how many times a given character appears in the string. Every time a character appears in the string, the array element corresponding to the ASCII value of that character is incremented by one.

The elements in `array_count []` are all set to `0` by your `memset()`. Then your loop iterates through `s[]`. So in the first iteration:

```
array_count [s[i]]++   // first evaluate [i]
array_count [s[0]]++   // i is zero
array_count ['a']++    // s[0] is 'a'
array_count [97]++     // promotion of 'a' from char to int; ASCII value of 'a' is 97
```

`array_count [97]` is zero because of the `memset`, so because of the `++` it gets incremented to 1.

Similar magic happens with the rest of the characters in subsequent iterations; when the loop terminates, `array_count [97]` will be 2 because of the two `'a'`s in `"aloha"`; `array_count [0]` will be 1 because of the `NUL` character at the end of `"aloha"`; and you can figure out what the rest of the array will be (mostly zeros).

Comment: Thanks for the step by step explanation of the statement. Pretty clear now with the concept.

Comment: Note that this is a conceptual explanation, not an actual model of what happens in memory. The compiler might optimize the code differently.

Comment: Yes, I get that. This helps in understanding the statement better.

Answer (score 2):

Each `char` in `s[]` has an `unsigned int` value (usually it's ascii value) inclusively between `0` and `255`.  `array_count[]` is initialised to all zeros by the `memset`. Then, by iterating through `s[]` from start to end with `i` in the `for` loop, the value of each `char` is used to index into `array_count[]` and increment it's value with `++`.  So you get a count of the `char` values in `s[]`.

Comment: Splendid.That was very elaborate.Clears all my questions.Thanks!

Comment: Except without an explicit cast, `char` is signed by default on the most used platforms... Which means if the string contained any non-ASCII character, it would lead to Undefined Behavior from indexing the array with a negative value.

Comment: Is there a different method for checking a string with non-ASCII characters ? What sort of explicit cast would I require ?

Answer (score 0):

256 is possible letter in string. see the ascii table.

http://www.asciitable.com/

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++) 
{ 
     array_count[s[i]]++;    // What exactly happens in this statement ?? 

for i=0

 s[i] = 'a'

ascii value of 'a' is 97

so it will increment arry_count[97] value from 0 to 1



}
```